# Synchronization of particular shared memory write operations (MPI)

Tags: c++, mpi, shared-memory, race-condition, atomic

To keep things simple and in order to concentrate on the core of my problem, let's assume that a memory location, addressed locally by a pointer variable `ptr`, is shared among several processes. I in particular use MPI shared memory windows in C/++ to allocate and share the memory. To be concrete, let's say `ptr` references a floating point variable, so locally we have

```
float* ptr;
```

Now assume that all processes attempt to write the same value `const float f` to ptr, i.e.

```
*ptr = f;
```

My question is: Does this operation require synchronization, or can it be executed concurrently, given the fact that all processes attempt to modify the bytes in the same way, i.e. given the fact that `f` has the same value for every process. My question therefore boils down to: For concurrent write operations to e.g. floating point variables, is there the possibility that the race condition results in an inconsistent byte pattern, although every process attempts to modify the memory in the same way. I.e. if I know for sure that every process writes the same data, can I then omit synchronization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you must synchronize the shared memory. the fact that the modifying threads reside in different processes has no meaning, it is still data race (writing to a shared memory from different threads).

do note that there are other problems that synchronization objects solve, like visibility and memory reordering, what is written to the shared memory is irrelevant.

currently, the standard does not define the idea of a process (only thread), and does not provide any means of synchronizing between processes easily.

you allocate a `std::mutex` in a shared memory and use that as you synchronization primitive, or rely on a win32 inter-process synchronization primitives like a mutex, semaphore or event.

alternatively, if you only want to synchronize a primitive, you can allocate a `std::atomic<T>` on a shared memory and use that as your synchronized primitive.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Can you say in more detail what you mean by "resize in different processes has no meaning"? If I implemented a proper synchronization in MPI (which sure I know how to do), I would not even use synchronization objects. So I do not understand how "visibility, memory reordering" factors in? I sure would not use any C++ standard library feature to solve the problem. Please also note that the conflict is between different processes accessing the data, not threads.

Comment: It is a typo, it is "reside". if your MPI provides synchronization, this is a different question, I have answered based on your example, e.g. write to a naked pointer from different processes

Comment: So what could go wrong here in terms of memory reordering with multiple processes writing the same data, i.e. what could go wrong on assembly level?

Comment: @sperber in a nutshell, the compiler and the CPU are un-aware that multiple threads are about to write/read from the variable and can optimize the code in a wrong manner. the compiler can merge `++*f; ++*f;` to `*f += 2`, for example, breaking any logic that other threads that read from `f` rely on.

Comment: I understand that, but I am really talking about this particular example of writing the same data value to the same memory location. How can the interference cause an  invalid byte pattern, i.e. how can the byte pattern depend on the execution?

Comment: @sperber thesedays, compiler are bitches. if they notice you have UB in your code, they just screw your program's logic.

Comment: But the compiler does not even know that there are multiple processes, so it is certainly not one of those "yeah, we (the compiler) are allowed to REALLY do that, the standard says it is UB, although it doesn't make sense what we are doing" kind of situations...

Comment: @sperber this is as equally dangerous, as the compiler can think your program is completely mono-threaded and can elide the writing to `ptr`, or not to elide the writing - but never really take a look at what `ptr` is having. if you never read from `ptr`, then why write there at the first place?

Answer (score 1):

In C++, if multiple processes write to the same memory location without proper use of synchronization primitives or atomic operations, undefined behavior occurs. (That is, it might work, it might not work, the computer might catch on fire.)

In practice, on your computer, it's basically certain to work the way you think it should work. It actually is plausible that on some architectures things don't go the way you expect, though: If the CPU cannot read/write a block of memory as small as your shared value, or if the storage of the shared value crosses an alignment boundary, such a write can actually involve a read as well, and that read-modify-write can have the effect of reverting or corrupting other changes to memory.

The easiest way to get what you want is simply to do the write as a "relaxed" atomic operation:

```
std::atomic_store_explicit(ptr, f, std::memory_order_relaxed);
```

That ensures that the write is "atomic" in the sense of not causing a data race, and won't incur any overhead except on architectures where there would be potential problems with `*ptr = f`.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you, these are exactly the details and hints I am looking for / suspecting.

Comment: Note that this is one of *very very few* situations where `memory_order_relaxed` is actually a good idea. In general, all accesses to shared memory should either be protected with synchronization primitives, or done with stronger memory orderings.